My husband's company signed him up for a LIMITED FSA (Vision & Dental only) vs. a regular one. THEIR fault. Can it be fixed?
My employer has amazing medical insurance so my husband & I are covered for medical through them. He has dental and vision for us through his employer and also contributes to an FSA (since he makes a lot more money than I do). I deal with the bills and kept getting denials for FSA reimbursements and couldn't figure out why and finally today discovered it is because when his employer enrolled him in the FSA this time the person doing it in the HR dept apparently selected a Limited Purpose FSA, but never mentioned that to him (we didn't even know that was a thing until today). He's worked for this company for 22 yrs and this has never happened before (and we've been using my medical coverage for 6 years now with no problems). When he signed up for the FSA it wouldn't go through on the online portal so someone in their benefits department did it manually and we assumed everything was the same as before until now (the benefits year started March 1, so open enrollment is closed, of course). Again, this was THEIR fault and not his.
Is there a way to fix this? Both the FSA admin company and the Benefits help desk at his company is acting like we're just out of luck, but I can't believe that's the case.
Can someone tell me what can be done (if anything) about this?

Does he also have an HSA?  Normally you can't have both an HSA and FSA, but you can have both an HSA and a limited purpose FSA, increasing the amount of pretax dollars overall.

LPFSA comes with HDHP and HSA, do any of these ring a bell?

Why can't you believe this is the case?  While yes, it was someone else's fault, but that does not change IRS regulations which are quite strict.
